# Why does Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) not autoscale user node pool

Tags: azure-aks

I'm running an azure kubernetes service with 1 system pool (agentpool) and 1 user pool (userpool).

The agentpool has a `CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule` taint to avoid being used by non critical pods and is configured for autoscaling from 1 to 5 nodes.

The userpool is configured for autoscaling from 0 to 5 nodes.

I'm trying to test the autoscaling by running a lot of pods on the user node in the hope that the autoscaler kicks in and starts a second userpool node.

Looking at the events, I'm seeing pods being evicted due to a lack of resources like the following:

```
Evicted                        pod/runner-ypq5fqbh-project-635-concurrent-594whk          The node was low on resource: memory. Container helper was using 10272Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container svc-0 was using 30116Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container build was using 1681384Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
```

and

```
EvictionThresholdMet           node/aks-userpool-27234786-vmss000004                      Attempting to reclaim memory
```

I tried to keep scheduling pods for several minutes. In the meantime I watched the cluster-autoscaler-status and could not find any evidence of a second node being started:

```
kubectl describe configmap --namespace kube-system cluster-autoscaler-status
Name:         cluster-autoscaler-status
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/last-updated: 2022-05-18 14:30:15.943110841 +0000 UTC

Data
====
status:
----
Cluster-autoscaler status at 2022-05-18 14:30:15.943110841 +0000 UTC:
Cluster-wide:
  Health:      Healthy (ready=2 unready=0 notStarted=0 longNotStarted=0 registered=2 longUnregistered=0)
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 2022-05-18 14:10:45.260804967 +0000 UTC m=+949.745935672
  ScaleUp:     NoActivity (ready=2 registered=2)
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 2022-05-18 14:21:04.140370827 +0000 UTC m=+1568.625501532
  ScaleDown:   NoCandidates (candidates=0)
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

NodeGroups:
  Name:        aks-agentpool-27234786-vmss
  Health:      Healthy (ready=1 unready=0 notStarted=0 longNotStarted=0 registered=1 longUnregistered=0 cloudProviderTarget=1 (minSize=1, maxSize=5))
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 2022-05-18 14:10:45.260804967 +0000 UTC m=+949.745935672
  ScaleUp:     NoActivity (ready=1 cloudProviderTarget=1)
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 2022-05-18 14:10:45.260804967 +0000 UTC m=+949.745935672
  ScaleDown:   NoCandidates (candidates=0)
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

  Name:        aks-userpool-27234786-vmss
  Health:      Healthy (ready=1 unready=0 notStarted=0 longNotStarted=0 registered=1 longUnregistered=0 cloudProviderTarget=1 (minSize=0, maxSize=5))
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
  ScaleUp:     NoActivity (ready=1 cloudProviderTarget=1)
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 2022-05-18 14:21:04.140370827 +0000 UTC m=+1568.625501532
  ScaleDown:   NoCandidates (candidates=0)
               LastProbeTime:      2022-05-18 14:30:15.934929647 +0000 UTC m=+2120.420060352
               LastTransitionTime: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC



BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

Any idea's why this does not work?

I'm using Kubernetes version 1.22.6 using `Standard_D2as_v5` for both user and agent pools.